# Trying to find an element to click

Tags: protractor

I am trying to identifying an element on the following code, to get a button click on protractor, any comments would be appreciated. thanks

```
<div class="button-wrapper ng-scope">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg add-member" ng-click="addForm()">
        <span ng-bind="'settings.xxx_xxxx_xxxx.add_form' | translate" class="ng-binding">
            xxx xxxx xxxx Form
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: try xpath `//a[contains(. , 'xxx xxxx xxxx Form')]`

Comment: yong, thank you so much , works like charm